# ‘Alive’ in phrase ‘get out alive’

Tags: adjectives

There are no adverb *alive*, but how is ‘get out alive’ grammatical? Is *alive* an adjectival complement? However, *get out* is not copular and a predicative adjective should be after a linking verb.

The whole building was on fire - we were lucky to get out alive!

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/get-out

Comment: 'Alive' is an adjective. It's a book title, so it does not need to be a complete sentence. "[We] get out alive", or "Get out alive!" Also the *tooth* came out *whole*, the *bones* were picked *clean*...

Comment: @Weather Vane But there are no linking verbs (a.k.a. copular verbs).

Comment: In the three I mention, the verbs are  'get', 'came out' and 'were picked' between the noun (implied in the first one) and the adjective. The usage is similar to what's shown [here](https://www.englishgrammar.org/copular-verbs/).

Comment: I mean get out, pick and come out are not copular verbs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usage is very common.

1a. John left the jail happily.  (He left in a happy manner)

1b. John left the jail happy. (He left while being in a happy state)

In 1a we imagine John walking out of the jail joyfully. However this only lasts for the duration of his exit. In 1b we think of his continuing mental state.

---

2a. John left the jail rapidly. (He left in a rapid manner)

2b. John left the jail rapid. (Incorrect. There is no state of 'rapidness')

---

3a. John left the jail alively. (Incorrect there is no 'manner' in which one is alive)

3b.  John left the jail alive.  (He left the jail in a state of being alive)

---

To sum up we must distinguish between a manner and a state. Some descriptive words can have adjective and adverb. Some can have only adjective, and some can have only adverb.

Comment: You are a genius!

Comment: Hi but  that adjective can also modify the object?

Comment: Or only subject